# Use shouldOverrideUrlLoading to handle commands on Android WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm new to Android, and I'm working on a simple WebView app.
I'm using **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** to handle some commands from my remote HTML to Android.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
if(!url.startsWith("https://www.mywebsite.com)) {
    switch (url) {
        case "mycmd://app_logoff":
            Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.logoff_ok), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            appLogoff();
            break;

        default:
            view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlWeb)));
    }
}

return true;
```

I tested on my Android device (Motorola X Play) and it worked good! Is it safe to say that this will work on all android devices that matches the app minimum API level? Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` means you are implementing the custom `WebViewClient` and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` should give your app a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView.

As per the developer [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) this API is added in **API Level 1** so that basically means it is supported since long and should not be a concern as far as minimum API level.

I guess no one can surely say that it will work or not work on ALL devices unless actually tested on them. You may want to test them using Android emulators with different configurations such as different SDK/Platforms, API Level etc. to be double sure.

As a side note and **caution**, This method is not called for requests using the **POST** "method".

Answer (score -1):

from webview android exapmle, shouldOverrideUrlLoading is used.
However, it is deprecated since api 24.

[boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view,  String url)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String))

New replacement API with new parameter is here.

[boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))

Comment: sorry, i'm new here, just fix it

Comment: I would edit the previous answer rather than writing a new one!

Comment: I disagree with Derek, because i'm answering the question, not giving comment to others' reply.

Comment: I mean actually edit the answer, not write a comment to it.  It sounds like the change you are making is because the API has changed- so it would be best to actually reflect that in the chosen answer.